# ArrayList giving problems in java. positive integers solution to x+y+z+w = 13

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, integer, combinations

So i am creating a method that basically gives all possible positive integer solutions to the problem x+y+z+w = 13. Really I have designed a program that can get all possible positive integer solutions to any number using any number of variables. I have managed to obtain the solution using this method:

```
public class Choose {

    public static ArrayList<int[]> values;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int[] loops = new int[3];
        int q = 0;
        values = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        int[] array = new int[4];
        System.out.println(choose(12,3));
        NestedLoops(3,10,0,loops,13,array, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++){
            printArray(values.get(i));
        }

    }

    public static void NestedLoops(int n, int k, int j, 
                                       int[] loops, int q, int[] array, int g){
        if(j==n){
            for(int i = 0; i< n; i++){
                q-=loops[i];
            }
            if(q>0){
                for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
                    array[i] = loops[i];
                }
                array[n] = q;
                values.add(array);
            }
            return;
        }
        for(int count = 1; count <= k; count++){
            loops[j] = count;
            NestedLoops(n,k,j+1,loops, 13, array, g);
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that when i go to print the ArrayList, all i get is the last value repeated again and again. When i try to just print out the values instead of storing them in the ArrayList it works totally fine. This makes me think that the problem is with the values.add(array); line but i don't know how to fix it or what i am doing wrong. Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: it would help to have the `printArray` function.

Comment: `This makes me think that the problem is with the values.add(array); ` You can print array right before `values.add(array)`, this way you'll know for sure. You can also use debugging to check contents of `values` on each step of the algorithm.

Comment: You operate with a **single** array object. You then store references to this (one) array in your `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
values.add(array.clone());
```

Every add of the same array just points to that array object. As you keep changing the same object, the final state is what is being shown for all stored elements. The print works as it just dumps the state of the array at that particular instant.

Comment: Thanks. I was stumped by this didn't realize it was such a small mistake.